# Bluetooth Low Energy - Linux with BlueZ

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, adafruit

I'm working on a project where I need to establish connection between my computer and a **Adafruit feather 32u4 with BLE** incorporated.
Due to comments on lots of webs, I decided to **use linux** to do the job.
I got everything installed and **I can connect my BLE with the PC successfully**.

----MY CONNECTION PROCEDURE-----

I can even recieve data and send data between them with gatttool.
To connect both devices i use this commands:

- sudo hcitool lescan
- sudo gatttool -t random -b F6:E5:F4:A7:71:E6 -I
- connect

The devices are connected correctly. I can use all the gatttool commands and they respond as expected.

----END OF CONNECTION PROCEDURE----

---MAIN PROBLEM---

I don't know how I could implement all the commands in a packed C program. 
I need to be able to manage all the commands in the same program !! without using brute force with system().

It would be great if someone could show me how gatttool do its magic.

**I mainly need to know how to get the data from Rx and how to send it to Tx via code not commands.**

Note: I can supply any further information if needed.

Comment: I used the sample code from here to gert started: https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html

Comment: @bruceg That article seems for normal bluetooth not bluetooth low Energy.

Comment: It worked for me for my ble dongle

Comment: could you please tell me how did you connected a BLE device with that code? I mean... it is a basic hcitoolkit scan and it doesn't work for Ble! To look for ble devices you should do a lescan. Can you explain how you solved that?@bruceg

Comment: Our device has a USB and I used a CSR dongle that was using BLE

Comment: doesn't work for me :(